# Can a Raspberry Pi boot a small OS/application off of a floppy disk?

Tags: gpio, usb, connection

Is it possible to develop a small OS/script for the Raspberry Pi that can boot from a floppy disk? If so what knowledge and tools would be needed to accomplish this?

i.e. No sd card, just a floppy disk drive connected via USB.

Comment: first step is to see if raspberry pi can even access a floppy disk - then of course there's the fact that floppy disks aren't usually partitioned - to be honest, I don't know why you'd want to use technology that hasn't been used in the mainstream for 20+ years - especially as a boot drive! I can understand maybe to read some old disks or something, but boot? why would you want the pi to boot so slowly!! If it is possible, it would only be possible for pi3 and newer anyway, not pi0, pi(1) or pi2

Comment: It's cheaper than a Commodore 64 on ebay...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are really two parts to this question.  Can you boot from floppy, and can you put an OS on a floppy.

As to whether you can put an OS on a floppy, yes of course you can.  Quite apart from the good old days of MS-DOS 3.1, CP/M, et al, I have written small OS that will run from a floppy, it isn't difficult.

As an intellectual exercise or learning process, go ahead.  You only need your favourite compiler.

As to whether you can boot from floppy - probably.  I have connected a 5.25" floppy to a Pi400 via USB.  Not to boot from, just to read, so go for it.

Comment: If the floppy drive presents itself transparently as a USB storage device, which presumably it does, then you should be able to boot from that on models which allow for such.  A slight complication may be that because you can't partition floppies you will have to figure out how to deal with whatever bits of firmware are required.  I used to boot minimal linux systems (kernel, bash shell, etc.) off 1-2 3.5" floppies!  Don't think you can't compile a useful kernel that small anymore.